# Liskov substitution principle violation

Tags: oop, solid-principles, liskov-substitution-principle

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle),

> Liskov's notion of a behavioral subtype defines a notion of
>   substitutability for objects; that is, if S is a subtype of T, then
>   objects of type T in a program may be replaced with objects of type S
>   without altering any of the desirable properties of that program (e.g.
>   correctness).

Suppose the following class hierarchy:

1. The base abstract class - `AnimalWithFur`. It has a read-only property `furColor` that is overridden in successors.
2. Base class's successor - `Cat`, which overrides `furColor` and returns *gray*.
3. Cat's successor - `Tiger`, which overrides `furColor` and returns *striped*.

Then we declare a method with an argument of type `Cat` (**not** `AnimalWithFur`).
Is sending a `Tiger` instance to that method a violation of the *L* in SOLID?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Strictly speaking, yes. The wiki article summation of Liskov says:

> "...in **a** program...without altering any of the **desirable properties** of **that** program"

If you go back to the [original paper](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/36be/babeb72287ad9490e1ebab84e7225ad6a9e5.pdf) by Barbara Liskov, it's **literally stricter** in its wording, **3.3.
Type Hierarchy**:

> If for each object o1 of type S there is an object o2 of type T such that for **all** programs P defined in terms of T, the behavior of P **is unchanged** when o1 is substituted for o2

(Empahsis mine)

So if you replace an instance of `Cat` with another instance that does something different, i.e. returning stripped not grey, then that is a Liskov violation in the original sense, because a program could be easily defined that relies on the color being grey, here:

```
program(Cat c){
   println(c.furColor);
}
```

The behaviour of that program **will change** if you pass it a `Tiger` in place of a `Cat`.

However, in the normal way LSP is applied, it is not a violation if you did not add extra preconditions or postconditions. This is a more practical, less academic definition as people accept that when replacing an instance of one concrete type with another you **do** intend to change the behaviour of the program while maintaining desirable properties of that program. So presuming the client code can handle stripped like any other colour, and grey was not required for a "desirable" property of the program then it does not violate.

Comment: does rewriting of parameter type to AnimalWithFur changes something?

Comment: No, because the property furColour is on AnimalWithFur. And you're still substituting a tiger for a cat because I have to assume that if your taking about LSP, you are substituting and you only have two concrete types; cat and tiger.

Comment: It may not even matter where the property is defined actually, if it changes the desirable properties of the program it's a LSP violation.

Comment: LSP comes in different flavors now? That's awfully convenient; it allows us to answer LSP questions by saying yes and no at the same time. Everything violates _strict_ LSP, but most things follow _normal_ LSP.

Comment: @jaco0646 I don't know about convenience, I explained both reasons. Which do you object to? However I certainly *did not* say everything violates strict LSP, I even said in this very case it depends whether the colour change makes an observable difference.

Comment: I object to redefining LSP as two separate categories. I doubt that Liskov herself applies the principle in two different ways. If there is another version of the principle, this answer should cite it for comparison.

Comment: @jaco0646 I have, I cited the original text from the original paper. If the color of the cat is changed by the subtype, **and** that **changes** the behavior of the program then it **is** a violation. The wiki is watered down, saying "altering desirable properties" in place of "unchanged". Those are the two. Tell me, what is your opinion on whether the OP's situation is a violation?

Comment: @jaco0646 I just added some extra emphasis, note that the original Liskov paper refers to **all** programs, and wiki Liskov refers to **a** program. So wider in scope, so again stricter in another sense.

Comment: This question poses a simple case of polymorphism. There is no LSP violation. Having had a couple of years to think about it, I am most persuaded by the explanation of LSP given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44445364/1371329).

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: not necessarily.  I'd have said not with the information you've given.  The key, for me, is that you don't say what the imagined new method is supposed to do.

You might consider the behaviour that you're requiring in your new method to be more important than the concern of a class hierarchy.

One way to do this is to define an interface for the behaviour your new method needs from the passed in instance / argument.

Then whichever class you might want to pass into that method can implement that interface and you break apart the concern of an inheritance hierarchy and move to being concerned with consistency of behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

Your question nicely describe why to use class composition instead of class inheritance. Firstly, your code is illogical - `Tiger` is not a `Cat` in your sense, `Tiger` is one of `Cats family.` From code point of view, it is bad design to override and totally replace the behavior of parent class, this is actually liskov substitution violation - your `Cat` class means defined cat with some concrete color, and application expects to work with it respectively, but you are overriding it with inconsistent type and change the behavior. 
If you would describe types hierarchy correctly, you would have abstract type `Cat` without furColor implemented, and types `Tiger` and `HomeCat`, but `HomeCat` could have different color, isn't?

If you want to have trivial example of LS violation, e.g.:
You are extending `List` interface with custom implementation, returning size always 10, but with different count of objects inside. Each normal application expects to work with list using for statement, but will have unpredictable behavior because you've broken LS principle, and List object does not behave as it is expected.

Comment: I don't entirely agree with you about class hierarchy, but even with your remarks - my code is only about an example, it's not designed to be the best solution :) It's easy enough to understand and draw parallels with existing, and using widely examples, as for me. Nevertheless, I like your note about composition. Good remark