# Liskov Substetution principle vs polymorphism

Tags: php, polymorphism, solid-principles, liskov-substitution-principle

According to the definition of LSP: If class B is a child class of class A, that object of class a can be replaced by object of class b. Here an example to make it clear:

```
<?php
class Counter 
{
    protected $counter = 0;

    public function incrementCounter(int $incrementBy): self
    {
        $this->counter = $this->counter + $incrementBy;
        return $this;
    }
}

class SubCounter extends Counter
{
    public function incrementCounter(int $incrementBy): self
    {
        $this->counter = $this->counter - $incrementBy;
        // perhaps some other stuff
        return $this;
    }
}
```

As you can see in the example above: both classes have the same method. Method has the same signature - the same arguments and return type. If we replace object of Counter with object of SubCounter, everything will be fine. But there is one issue, even though method of SubCounter is called "increment" - it has an opposite behavior. It decrements value. That's how polymorphism works. So "Does it means that polymorphism itself violates LSP"?

Comment: Perhaps it means that the naming of the method as `incrementCounter` is incorrect.

Comment: It's important to remember the LSP covers both syntax and semantics. It covers both what the method is coded to do, and what the method is documented to do. This means vague (or missing) documentation can make it difficult (or impossible) to apply the LSP. I wrote this in response to another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61780911/is-this-precondition-a-violation-of-the-liskov-substitution-principle) but it is relevant here as well. LSP violations cannot be determined simply by parsing code (in most languages).